# Chart.js problems with xAxes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

The problem is this. My xAxes is not showing(time), as well as the backgroundColor of the chart, but my labels and data are being displayed. Where could be the location of the problem? Please help me

```
const chartInstance = new Chart(chartCanvasRef.current, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: `${detail.name} price`,
            data: determineTimeFormat(timeFormat, day, week, year),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(134,159,152, 1)',
            borderColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.4",
            pointRadius: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        lineHeightAnnotation: {
          always: true,
          hover: true,
          lineWeight: 1.5,
        },
      
        animation: {
          duration: 2000,
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }],
          xAxes: [         
            {  
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                autoSkip: false,
                display: true,
            },
              type: "time",
              distribution: "linear"
            },
            
          ],
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js xAxes not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662667/chart-js-xaxes-not-showing)

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: Stack automatically post those comments on duplicate flags, which this is, so instead of reposting try to improve your question

Comment: @mura1 please provide some data to test, it would be possible to provide a jsfiddle example?